# Pandas groupby object back to a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I'm trying to split a pandas Dataframe into two separate data frames by a single binary variable. Accordingly, the groupby function seems a decent option except it doesn't return a data frame but rather a groupby object which isn't nearly as useful to me. Moreover, I can't access any values from within the groupby object. I ran a simple df.groupby('Type') statement and would like to partition the data from here meaning output those two groups to two new data frames. Any help would be sincerely appreciated. The last question I posted was met with ridiculously childish admonitions not to post homework questions. Needless to say, this as well as the aforementioned were/are NOT homework so please spare me of such remarks. As always thanks so much.

Comment: Why doesn't groupby work for you (what are you intending to do next)? It is useful! ...You shouldn't worry about people's comments re "homework", although I think you could improve this question with some sample code (see http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Comment: groupby would work i just dont know how to automate/iterate through using group by

Comment: sorry different question...i have posed two recently please disregard. thanks again.

Comment: It could be an groupby's apply will do it, like I say in other question, depends what you're doing!

Answer (score 4):

If you use groupby, you can iterate through the groups as follows:

```
g = df.groupby('class')

for k, v in g.groups.iteritems():
    print k  # a
    print df.iloc[v]  # df_a, the dict values are position indices for the group
    print

a
  class     data1       data2
0     a -0.173070  141.437719
2     a -0.087673  200.815709
6     a  1.220608  159.456053
8     a  0.428373   -6.491034
9     a -0.123463  -96.898025

c
  class     data1       data2
5     c -0.358996  162.715982
7     c -1.339496   23.043417

b
  class     data1      data2
1     b -1.761652 -12.405066
3     b  1.366879  22.988654
4     b  1.125314  60.489373
```

*Note: iterating over a set/dict is not guaranteed to be in order.*

Comment: Thanks for posting this, Andy.  I was just about to post this nice, more general solution, too.  I went with the one above because he'd said his `class` variable was binary.  But this is a much nicer way to handle things.  And thanks for pointing out the actual contents of the `groups` dictionary.  I.e. that the values in `groups` are *not* the sub-data-frames, but instead are the integer locations of the appropriate rows in the *original* data frame.

Comment: `for k, v in g.groups.items():` is the syntax for python 3.x.

Answer (score 2):

How's this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({'class': np.random.choice(list('abc'), size=10),
                   'data1': np.random.randn(10),
                   'data2': np.random.randn(10) * 100})

df_a = df[df['class']=='a']
df_b = df[df['class']=='b']
df_c = df[df['class']=='c']

print df, '\n'

print df_a
print df_b
print df_c
```

Gives:

```
  class     data1       data2
0     a -0.173070  141.437719
1     b -1.761652  -12.405066
2     a -0.087673  200.815709
3     b  1.366879   22.988654
4     b  1.125314   60.489373
5     c -0.358996  162.715982
6     a  1.220608  159.456053
7     c -1.339496   23.043417
8     a  0.428373   -6.491034
9     a -0.123463  -96.898025 

  class     data1       data2
0     a -0.173070  141.437719
2     a -0.087673  200.815709
6     a  1.220608  159.456053
8     a  0.428373   -6.491034
9     a -0.123463  -96.898025
  class     data1      data2
1     b -1.761652 -12.405066
3     b  1.366879  22.988654
4     b  1.125314  60.489373
  class     data1       data2
5     c -0.358996  162.715982
7     c -1.339496   23.043417
```

Comment: sincerest of thanks. I'm really shocked in the 87 tutorials I saw no one had something this simple. i'm going to listen to some sabbath and then try this sick code out. you are the man.

Comment: the print function gives me something different:

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 0 entries
Data columns (total 66 columns):
#RIC                               0  non-null values
Date[G]                            0  non-null values
Time[G]                            0  non-null values
GMT Offset                         0  non-null values
Type                               0  non-null values

Comment: calling `print` on a data frame shows "a nice representation" of the data frame.  If there aren't too many rows or columns, it shows you the whole thing.  If there is a lot of data, it just gives you a summary about how much non-null data there is in each column.